# $_GET to dynamic URL

Tags: php, url, get

I have created dynamic url's like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test
```

But, if I send values via GET, I cannot get the values because the URL is structured like this:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test?value=1
```

How could I get the values without using POST? This is because I use a third-party app and they only support GET.

Comment: You can include multiple GET variables in the URL like this: `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test&value01=a&value02=b&value03=c`

Comment: kdg123, They do the GET-ing so I cannot control it. When they GET, they do it like this `http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test?value=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create your dynamic url's like

`http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test&`

then you will get

`http://www.example.com/index.php?page=test&?value=1`

which I believe you should be able to work with.  You will then just have to look for the first parameter after your initial ? as `$_GET['?value']` I believe

Comment: How is it not working?  Does it truncate the extra '&' at the end or you just still can't get the variable?

Comment: Ah, Yes. I have done a print_r($_GET) and I have found the variable. However it is $_GET['first_variable?']. I think you should update it.

Comment: That literally blows my mind that the question mark is at the end of the first one?  I thought & was supposed to separate GET variables.  Good to know

Comment: Oops, my mistake, I have placed the ? and the & the other way round. You are right, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question, but you could assign a full list of variables separated with `&` except for the first one.

```
$page = 'test&value=1';
```

and then assign it to your url.